# In R huge difference between user and elapsed which is not equal to "system"

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel

I am running a script which uses 3 of the 4 cores of my windows machine using the function %dopar%.

I get the following statistics:

```
user  system elapsed 
1.19    0.06   75.83
```

Without the parallel utilization (i.e. using only one core), user and elapsed are almost equal and are equal to 120 sec.

Elapsed seems to be the actual time the program takes, and also makes sense (kind of) because it is roughly half the time of the non-parallel version (why not 1/3? because registering the cores wastes some time). But what does "user" mean in this case? Also, why isn't user + system = elapsed as is usually the case?

Comment: I disagree with rendering the question as duplicate. In the other question there wasn't such a big difference between user and elapsed

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42963771/324364) would be a better duplicate?

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669328/system-time-for-parallel-and-serial-processing?rq=1